# Snowflake 2 decimal places

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rounding, sqldatatypes

I have a data column that is a number and it has nulls, dashes, and commas. I want to remove all and replace with 0.00.  Also I have some numbers that are 11.4 instead of 11.40.  How do I fix this?
also something either nvl or round adds the comma back in.

I tried round, I tried doing ;;decimal(20,2), I tried a replace to 0.00. Nothing seems to work.

```
round(nvl(replace(replace(aum_total,'-',0),',',''),0)) as aum_total
```

Comment: can you show a table of "input" and wanted "output" because it help to cross reference with the words you have used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so you are converting dash to zero makes low sense, from a guessing intent.

and the coma point I assume to to remove thousands, so to add that back in needs to be done via [TO_CHAR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html) via [formatting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html#fixed-position-numeric-formats).

And the trailing zeros also is a formatting thing..

```
select
    column1 as aum_total
    ,translate(aum_total, '-', '0') as t1
    ,replace(t1, ',', '') as r1
    ,zeroifnull(r1) as z1
    ,to_number(z1, 20, 2) as n1
    ,to_char(n1, '9,999,999.00') as result
from values 
    (null),
    ('1-7'),
    ('1,8'),
    ('11.4'),
    ('11.40'),
    ('11.400'),
    ('11.1234'),
    ('1,234.567');
```

gives:

| AUM_TOTAL | T1 | R1 | Z1 | N1 | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | null | 0 | 0 | 0.00 |
| 1-7 | 107 | 107 | 107 | 107 | 107.00 |
| 1,8 | 1,8 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18.00 |
| 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.40 |
| 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.40 |
| 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.4 | 11.40 |
| 11.1234 | 11.1234 | 11.1234 | 11.1234 | 11.12 | 11.12 |
| 1,234.567 | 1,234.567 | 1234.567 | 1,234.567 | 1,234.57 | 1,234.57 |

Thinking about this more, I now assume you mean you want to replace a string that is only a dash, with zero, as that is standard accounting, and not all dashes, thus not mess-up negative numbers, so swapping to regexp_replace, and the number cast can be skip it seems also!

```
select
    column1 as aum_total
    ,trim(aum_total) as t1
    ,regexp_replace(t1, '^-$', '0') as r1
    ,replace(r1, ',', '') as r2
    ,zeroifnull(r2) as z1
    ,to_char(z1, '9,999,999.00') as result
from values 
    (null),
    (' - '),
    (' -10.123 '),
    ('-'),
    ('-10.123'),
    ('1,8'),
    ('11.4'),
    ('11.40'),
    ('11.400'),
    ('11.1234'),
    ('1,234.567');
```